# When can "shrink" size flags be used in combination with "expand" in Godot's container system?

Tags: godot, godot4

Godot's documentation of its [`SizeFlags`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_control.html#enum-control-sizeflags) mentions for the three "shrink-like" flags `SIZE_SHRINK_BEGIN`, `SIZE_SHRINK_CENTER`, and `SIZE_SHRINK_END`:

> It is mutually exclusive with `SIZE_FILL` and other shrink size flags, but can be used with `SIZE_EXPAND` in some containers.

Combining "shrink" with "expand" sounds counter-intuitive.

What would be an example of such a use case, i.e., which containers do allow this combination and is there a common semantic what "shrink and expand" should mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A container that is trying to fill some allotted space (that would be `VBoxContainer` or `HBoxContainer`) will see if it can fit the children at their minimum size. If there is space left, it might be distributed among the children.

That is controlled by `SIZE_EXPAND` and `stretch_ratio`: The children `Control`s with `SIZE_EXPAND` will get some of the extra space. They take as much of the total available extra space as is their `stretch_ratio` of the sum of all the `stretch_ratio` of it and siblings with `SIZE_EXPAND`.

Once we have the space available for a `Control` then it either takes all that space (if it has `SIZE_FILL`) or it might be placed at the end of the space (`SIZE_SHRINK_END`), centered on the space (`SIZE_SHRINK_CENTER`) or at the start (`SIZE_SHRINK_BEGIN`, i.e. none of the others).

Thus using `SIZE_EXPAND` but not `SIZE_FILL` (i.e. combining expand and shrink) will result in giving more space to the `Control` but keeping its minimum size.

For example, if you have a `HBoxContainer` with multiple children with `SIZE_EXPAND` and `SIZE_SHRINK_CENTER`, they will be distributed horizontally with large gaps while keeping their minimum size. On the other hand, if you used `SIZE_EXPAND` and `SIZE_FILL` they would be as taking as much space as possible with minimum gaps between them. If you didn't use `SIZE_EXPAND`, then they would be at their minimum size and packed together with minimum gaps between them.